# bash parse space delimited text file

Tags: bash, awk, seed

example file

```
aaa [bbb bb] ccc "ddd dd" eee
bbb [ccc cc] ddd "eee ee" fff
```

expected:

```
line1
s1="aaa", s2="bbb bb", s3="ccc", s4="ddd dd", s5="eee"
line2
s1="bbb", s2="ccc cc", s3="ddd", s5="eee ee", s5="fff"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try for yourself? and what are the variable `s1` to `s5`. You want them stored in multiple variables? Why not an array

Comment: how about parenthesis, curly braces, single quotes?

Comment: I tried AWK. awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'  , not sure what to put delimiter -F

Comment: It would help to use a standard file format, and a language that already has a parser for that format.  This type of data processing really isn't what the shell is intended for.

Comment: agreed. I am a java guy however I have to use bash to parse this type of log file. Thank you

Comment: You posted input and output, or do you want to have bash variables set that way? I find this question as unclear. Also, bash uses no `,` as a separator nowhere, you want to have a `,` character suffixed to all variables?

Comment: This is not "space-delimited".

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk` you may use this:

```
awk -v OFS=", " -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*\\]|"[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^[["]|[]"]$/, "", $i)
      $i = "s" i "=\"" $i "\""
   }
   $0 = "line" NR ORS $0
} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
line1
s1="aaa", s2="bbb bb", s3="ccc", s4="ddd dd", s5="eee"
line2
s1="bbb", s2="ccc cc", s3="ddd", s4="eee ee", s5="fff"
```

Answer (score 0):

bash-only -

```
$: IFS=']"[' read -a line < infile # read the "groups"
$: line=( "${line[@]% }" )         # strip training spaces
$: line=( "${line[@]# }" )         # strip leading spaces
```

The `line` array now has your scrubbed data.

Shown in steps -

```
$: IFS=']"[' read -a line < infile
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${line[@]}"
[aaa ]
[bbb bb]
[ ccc ]
[ddd dd]
[ eee]
$: line=( "${line[@]% }" )
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${line[@]}"
[aaa]
[bbb bb]
[ ccc]
[ddd dd]
[ eee]
$: line=( "${line[@]# }" )
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${line[@]}"
[aaa]
[bbb bb]
[ccc]
[ddd dd]
[eee]
```